# How to fix corruption when expanding multiple panels in PrimeNG?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm working with multiple panels and I added functionality to **expand/collapse** them all. My issue is that when I expand them I see an **ugly corruption text** from all the panels. Does anyone know how to fix that? Here's my working code:
 [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/C4nKGKWGVwMJRyi2pQ5J?p=preview)

```
 <p-panel header="Panel 1" [toggleable]="true" [collapsed]="collapsed" [style]="{'margin-bottom':'20px'}">

 The story begins as Don Vito Corleone, the head of a New York Mafia family, oversees his daughter's wedding.
His beloved son Michael has just come home from the war, but does not intend to become part of his father's business.
Through Michael's life the nature of the family business becomes clear. The business of the family is just like the head of the family,
kind and benevolent to those who give respect, but given to ruthless violence whenever anything stands against the good of the family.

</p-panel>
```

Comment: Define corruption please.

Comment: am not gonna add it as an answer but you can find the explication here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731110/strange-behavior-of-background-when-elements-are-overlapping ;)

Comment: all your elements overlap and thus all the content is going above

Comment: @TemaniAfif : I was just about to link your question. Good Read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey not that familiar with angular nor the library you are using there. But you can avoid the overlapping part with some background and by setting a position attribute.

```
.ui-panel {
  position: relative;
}
.ui-panel .ui-panel-content.ui-widget-content { 
     background: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help bro!

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are trying to open all of them at once, and if you see closely, when you close them, they are all very close to each other, and then when you open them out, they `overlap`, now, I'm not sure if that is intended, but how they should open is just start from their current positions and spread down, just like when you `collapse/extend` only ONE of them.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker with the solution please? Thanks

Comment: You can't achieve what you are looking for with `p-panel` component, try using `accordion` or something else