# floats and Stacking Context

Tags: html, css, css-float, w3c

As background, below are the two relevant sections from W3C's CSS2.1 specification, [chapter 9](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#z-index).

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in
>   back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

...and this:

> Within each stacking context, positioned elements with stack level 0
>   (in layer 6), non-positioned floats (layer 4), inline blocks (layer
>   5), and inline tables (layer 5), are painted as if those elements
>   themselves generated new stacking contexts, except that their
>   positioned descendants and any would-be child stacking contexts take
>   part in the current stacking context.

**Questions**

- When we say that a "new stacking context" is generated by an element, does that mean that ONLY itself and its descendant (child/containing) elements are ordered in accordance to the new stacking context, and that that whole new stacking context is ordered (atomically) withing the root's stacking context (assuming no other contexts)?
- In the code below, I have a float, non-inline/non-positioned descendants of root, and inline-level/non-positioned descendants. Regardless, the float is not painted on top of the non-inline-level (block-level) box, as the spec seems to say it should. Only the background is painted on top of. Why is that?

```css
.float {
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: -25px;
  border: 5px solid green;
  float: left;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
.old {
  background: aqua;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.new {
  background: yellow;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
 <span class="old">tesssss</span>
 <div class="float">testTwo</div>
 <div class="new">foo</div>
```

Comment: You may want to read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731110/strange-behavior-of-background-when-elements-are-overlapping ;) you will probably find your answer there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question if we check the [painting order](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html) we will have this order:

> 4. For all its in-flow, non-positioned, block-level descendants in tree order:
> 5. If the element is a block, list-item, or other block equivalent: background color of element.

So now we have painted the background color of the block element `.new`

> 5. All non-positioned floating descendants, in tree order. For each one of these, treat the element as if it created a new stacking
>    context, but any positioned descendants and descendants which actually
>    create a new stacking context are considered part of the parent
>    stacking context, not this new one.

So now we have painted  **all the element** `.float` (background and content) because it creates it own stacking context. So we should paint everything inside it considering the painting order rules then we move to the next elements.

> 7. Otherwise: first for the element, then for all its in-flow, non-positioned, block-level descendants in tree order:
>
>    1. ...

At this step we will paint the content of the `.new` element and the inline element `.old`

---

So the trick is that the `.new` element is painted in two different steps, first it's background and later it's content. Between these steps we painted the floated element.

Comment: Thanks, Temani. What is that new spec you linked to? It seems to be a draft for a newer version of the CSS spec (since it is Level 3, and the last official version was Level 2)? Should we not go by the current official version CSS2.1? Lastly, CSS2.1 does not seem to go into as much detail regarding the painting order. Was it left up to the individual User Agent implementations? Maybe @BoltClock has some input.

Comment: I actually found the definition you shared in the official version (CSS2.1, Appendix E): https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/zindex.html#painting-order . Order is restored :)

Comment: @Magnus you was faster :p was going to tell that it's the same, to know this read read the abstract and you will see the difference. For this one you can read this : `The main extensions compared to level 2 are the ability to position elements based on CSS Region boxes, the ability to specify different containing blocks for elements and sticky positioning.` ... so we can say that the order painting is almost the same ;) and I personnaly like this link :p