# Lower z-indexed parent's child upon higher z-indexed element?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to manipulate the stacking context this way? I want the text to be on the top of the blue element.

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

#a{
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: red;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
}
#b{
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
p{
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <p>verylongtext</p>
</div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Is there any wild card or something like `!important` which can override the stacking context? The only way to do this is make the text an independent element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, the trick is to keep the red element with `z-index:auto` so that `p` will not belong to its stacking context and can be placed above the blue element.

> **auto**
>
> The box **does not** establish a new local stacking context. The
>   stack level of the generated box in the current stacking context is
>   **the same as its parent's box**.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)</sup>

Don't forget to make the `p` positioned in order to be able to use `z-index`:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

#a {
  background-color: red;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
}

#b {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

p {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <p>verylongtext</p>
</div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

You can also remove everything and play only with margin:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#a {
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  overflow:hidden; /*remove margin-collapsing*/
}

#b {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: -350px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <p>verylongtext</p>
</div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

You can refer to this question ( [Strange behavior of background when elements are overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731110/strange-behavior-of-background-when-elements-are-overlapping)) to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunately impossible to break the stacking context in this way, as a child's **[`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)** is set to the same stacking index as its parent. You will need to make the text a sibling element, and additionally make sure it has a [**`position`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) other than `static` in order for the `z-index` to apply.

From here, it's a simple matter of positioning it as desired (in this case with `top: 150px` and `left: 150px`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

#a {
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: red;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
}

#b {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<p>verylongtext</p>
```