# Avoid Section Overlap by Fixed Header when Clicking Link: Problem with Paint Order

Tags: html, css

Assume you have a website with a `position: fixed` header. If we click internal (same-page) links, that header will overlap the content we are taken to via the link.

I created a solution to this problem, using a `pseudo-element` with negative margin, which takes advantage of *parent-child* *margin collapsing* to prevent header overlap from occurring.

In short summary, the pseudo-element's top margin collapses with main element's top margin, causing the pseudo-element to stay within main, but push main's content down while at the same time pull content above it downwards.

It works well, except main's background will paint on top of background of element above it.

That can probably be prevented with `position: relative` and `z-index` on all elements.

**My question:** Is there a better way? Also, is this the typical way this problem is solved?

A minimal working example can be found below.

**Note:** The pseudo-element has `background-color` set on it, just to illustrate its presence. That background should be removed when testing it.

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.foo {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.foo:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.main div {
  height: 100px;
}

.main::before {
  content: "pseudo-element (when removing its background-color, you see how .main unfortunately paints on top of foo)";
  display: block;
  background: green;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
}

.main2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#scroll" class="link">Fixed Header: Click Me!</a></div>

<div class="foo">foo: section</div>
<div class="foo">foo: section</div>
<div class="main" id="scroll">
  <div class="main2">main: section</div>
</div>
<!-- <div class="main" id="scroll">main</div> -->
```

Comment: the same problem is explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731110/strange-behavior-of-background-when-elements-are-overlapping ... and basically the solution is to play with painting order by adding removing properties that will change the order, so yes adding position:relative to some element (without the need of z-index) solve the issue

Comment: Haha, hi @TemaniAfif . Its been a while! Hope all is well. A bit frustrating to have to go and position every target element, but oh well... This functionality is so standard, it should be built into bootstrap or other libraries by default.

Comment: by the way where is your other question dealing with this? am not able to find it (the one that get wrongly close). You delete it?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Check out my comments on the answer below. Any thoughts?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Regarding your other comment above, I have no idea. Way overdue on sleep here, but can check tomorrow. Thanks for all the good discussions btw.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way?

it depends on what you mean by *better*. In all the cases, the solution shouldn't break any other functionality or the layout then we can consider it as a *good* solution.

> Also, is this the typical way this problem is solved?

The problem as you already noticed, involve [painting order](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html) so the typical way to solve such issue is to add/change some properties in order to adjust the painting order like we want. You may also notice that not only `z-index` changes order but other properties like `transform`, `filter`, `opacity`, `float`, etc.

---

For this particular case, you don't need to adjust `z-index` and make all the element positioned. You simply need to increase the `z-index` of the fixed header and make the scrolling element positioned:

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:1;
  top: 0;
}

.foo {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.foo:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  height: 100px;
  position:relative;
  background: blue;
}

.main div {
  height: 100px;
}

.main::before {
  content: "pseudo-element (when removing its background-color, you see how .main unfortunately paints on top of foo)";
  display: block;
  background: green;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
}

.main2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#scroll" class="link">Fixed Header: Click Me!</a></div>

<div class="foo">foo: section</div>
<div class="foo">foo: section</div>
<div class="main" id="scroll">
  <div class="main2">main: section</div>
</div>
<!-- <div class="main" id="scroll">main</div> -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an invisible anchor to be the target of the top link, and then add top padding equal to your header to that target:

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#anchor {
  padding-top: 40px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.foo {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.foo:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.main div {
  height: 100px;
}

.main2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#anchor" class="link">Fixed Header: Click Me!</a></div>

<div class="foo">foo: section</div>
<div class="foo">foo2ndchild: section</div>
<div class="main" id="scroll">
  <a id="anchor">not shown</a>
  <div class="main2">scrolling to this section</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This would have been a better solution, if it was not for the fact that the content inside main is pushed down. So the visible page after adding the header fix is not identical to what it was before adding the fix (which should be the goal). Any thoughts?

Comment: Actually, if you add a negative margin to top of main equal to line-height, you can pull it back up. The problem is that we cannot know the height of the content box of the anchor (<a>) element. We cannot turn it into a *block box* ufortunately, because this solution relies on the fact that padding of inline-level elements bleed into surrounding area (i.e. does not take affect *line box* height).

Comment: I created a pen here: https://codepen.io/magnusriga/pen/MqVGpa?editors=1100