# Bringing a HTML element to front with z-index on overflow in CSS

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to get the blue rectangle container to have a larger `z-index` than the other boxes when hovering over elements that `overflow` the container.

Game 3 here has the larger z-index, but I want to access the `Loser` `select` in the blue circle below, however I can't, unless I hover back over the blue rectangle to gain focus.

Is there a way around this where it can be handled with just CSS or do I need JQuery?

I created a Fiddle that can replicate this so ignore any JS errors as the actual page requires quite a bit of includes, however the issue is in tact. Hover over the 4th game which has three dropdowns, Source, Pools, Seeds. You can select Seeds just fine. However, hover over another game at the top then come back down to "Seeds", you can't select it unless you hover over "Pools" again. I need "Seeds" to always be selectable regardless of what the overflow is.

https://jsfiddle.net/cblaze22/qp4L15tj/8/

[image]

**Current Code For Game Hover (Blue Rectangle area)**

The .forward puts a large zindex on the blue rectangle area.

```
$(element).hover(
                function () {
                    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('editing')) {
                        $(this).addClass('forward');
                    }
                },
                function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('forward');
                }
            );
```

Comment: Please provide a code sample.

Comment: From what I see in the fiddle, the items do not overlap, so why mess with `z-index` in the first place? Is it due to inability to replicate the layout without absolutely positioned elements? Imho, this would be the way to go - and not only would you reduce the functionality required, but would not encounter any similar issues anyway.

Comment: There is a difference between the screenshot and the fiddle link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was actually a surprisingly easy fix once you understood the structure and the actual problem. Div's covering div's. First you disable all click events on everything within `.bracket-part` as they aren't needed. Then you add the click events back onto the selects. To make it more generic for easier use again you can simple change `select` in the CSS selector a class `.re-enable-events` or something. The JS about z-index's wasnt actually needed.

```
#bracket-wrapper .bracket-part select {
  pointer-events: all !important;
}
#bracket-wrapper .bracket-part {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/uws8pf1y/

[Pointer events](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) has a very good compatibility rate so this solution should be fine across pretty much all devices.

Comment: I tried that but not the child selector part, thanks alot!

Answer (score 6):

To get straight to the point: There is **no clean** CSS-only solution to your problem.
Since all your elements are pretty much identical (and by that I mean the `class` for example) you will not find a solution that covers all configurations. Since they do not differ from each other they all have the same `z-index` but not the same stacking context. Unless you give their parents a different `z-index` or change the stacking context you will not be able to access the blocked element. It also comes down to how limited you are with changing the code. The code looks like it has been build by JS and you just copied it to your fiddle for us to test.

#### Attempt #1

Attempt #1 is to just add high `z-index` directly to the according parent.
[@mmshr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6535388/mmshr) already tried to do this. However, he tried to give the whole class a high `z-index` which is not gonna work out of course as you've already pointed out.

You could however try to only give this element a high `z-index` element in its `style` attribute. This comes down to how limited you are with changing the code. You could theoretically use JQuery for this but the way you would select the element (e.g. by `nth-child()`) brings me to **Attempt #2**  which uses the same pseudo-class and is a CSS-only attempt so using JS is nonsense in this case. By the way if you can change your code like this you could remove your little JQuery function that adds the `forward` class on `hover`.

#### Attempt #2

This attempt works fine and you are not limited by the ability to change code since this is pretty much one line of CSS. As already stated in **Attempt #1** you could use a `pseudo-class` to select this element. However, this is not valid for all configurations. If you would add one element 
(`<div data-bind="template: { name: 'bracket-template', data: $data }">...</div>`) **before** your blocked element you would have to change your CSS each time. But if there is no need for changing elements and configurations (or at least not the order) this is a valid solution:

```
#bracket-wrapper > div > div:nth-child(8) > div > div {
  z-index: 2 !important;
}
```

In this attempt you can (and have to) remove your little JQuery function too:

```
$('.bracket-part').hover(
  function() {
    debugger;
    $(this).addClass('forward');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('forward');
  }
);
```

Remove the entire thing.

#### Attempt #3

Probably the cleanest and best attempt is to use the `stacking context`. The stacking context is explained right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731110/why-the-content-is-not-covered-by-the-background-of-an-adjacent-element-when-the). But to give you a simple overview ([W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index)):

> Each box belongs to one stacking context. Each positioned box in a given stacking context has an integer stack level, which is its position on the z-axis relative other stack levels within the same stacking context. Boxes with greater stack levels are always formatted in front of boxes with lower stack levels. Boxes may have negative stack levels. Boxes with the same stack level in a stacking context are stacked back-to-front according to document tree order.

Most important is this part because it applies to your structure:

> Boxes with the same stack level in a stacking context are stacked back-to-front according to document tree order.

If you take a look at your HTML tree you will find the following:
[image: HTML tree]

According to the stacking-context we should be able to give your element in the background a higher stacking-order then your element in the front by changing the order of those elements in your tree.

It is just a guess but you probably have something like an array where you store the data and some JS-file builds a tournament bracket out of it. If you could somehow change the order of those two elements (for example by changing the order of your array) you would not use CSS and would not use any additional JQuery.

#### What if none of these work?

Well, then I do not see any solution that requires only CSS.

I also thought about a possible JS solution but this is a tough one and I couldn't figure out a (simple) solution. Let me explain the problem:

Since your `select` is behind a `div` element JQuery would not recognize it (e.g.) on `hover` so you would have to use pseudo-classes again which I already covered with a CSS-only attempt. 
I also thought about adding a `z-index` of `-1` to the blocking element, because JQuery could recognize it on hover. But this leads to problems too: the blocking element is now in the background and the blocked element in the front and you can also click it. The problem is that the (former) blocking element is now behind the `#bracket-wrapper`. This is also not a valid solution because you would have to use a pseudo-class again to target this specific element.

#### Conclusion

I am gonna be honest with you: This tournament tree is poorly designed and structured. There shouldn't be overlapping elements or elements outside of a container and certainly not both in combination. If none of my attempts are suitable I do not see any CSS **or** JS solution. At least not a simple one. You have provided little information about how the tournament tree is build but things could change if you do.
At this state I think rebuilding this whole structure is the only really clean solution.

### Edit

#### Solution #1 by [@Deckerz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2622892/deckerz)

[@Deckerz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2622892/deckerz) provided a great solution which does not focus on the z-index. Instead, it uses `pointer-events`. I tried this approach but failed because I forgot an important part. The logic behind it is simple:

> First you disable all click events on everything within `.bracket-part` as they arent needed. Then you add the click events back onto the selects. To make it more generic for easier use again you can simple change `select` in the CSS selector a class `.re-enable-events` or something. The JS about z-index's wasnt actually needed.
>
> ```
> #bracket-wrapper .bracket-part select {
>    pointer-events: all !important;
> }
> #bracket-wrapper .bracket-part {
>    pointer-events: none;
> }
> ```

However, this is still a workaround. I still recommend restructuring your code and CSS.

Comment: Very nice and detailed analysis of the problem. But focusing on just using `z-index` was the reason it could not be done.

Comment: @Deckerz did you find another way with CSS only? I wasn't focusing on the `z-index` only. I also tried to work with `pointer-events` for example. Didn't work out. Where would you set your focus on a solution without JQuery?

Comment: See my answer below. I posted the solution

Comment: Nice answer! I also tried pointer-events but didn't manage to get it but I forgot to set the `pointer-events: all` to the `select` inputs... Is it okay if I mention your answer in my answer?

Comment: Go ahead my dude.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Seeds to *always* be selectable, why not always give it's `bracket-part` parent a high `z-index`?

Right now, the `z-index` is only high after the `bracket-part` is hovered. Although Seeds is technically a child of the `bracket-part`, it is positioned outside of it, so unless the Seeds select is hovered *directly* after `bracket-part` is hovered then it won't be selectable.

If you add `z-index: 10000;` to Seeds' `bracket-part` parent styles, Seeds will always be selectable:

```
<div class="part bracket-part ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-draggable-disabled ui-state-disabled" data-bind="bracketPartInit: { left: $data.left, top: $data.top, height: $data.height, width: $data.width, disabled: $root.members.bracket.disableDrag, minHeight: $data.minHeight }, css: { 'dash-top' : $data.dashedBorderTop(), 'dash-right' : $data.dashedBorderRight(), 'dash-bottom' : $data.dashedBorderBottom(), 'dash-left' : $data.dashedBorderLeft(), 'reverse-bracket' : $data.type() == 2, 'box-bracket': $data.type() == 13, 'bye': $data.bye()}" aria-disabled="true" style="top: 459px; left: 0px; height: 80px; width: 150px; z-index: 10000;">
```

Comment: All the other bracket-parts have seeds too so not that will not work.

Comment: How limited to changing the code are you? Can you change the order of elements in your code? So element one switches position with element two for example. It would not make a difference to its appearance since it is the same code in a different order. Let me know if you can.

Comment: @MikeFlynn I was suggesting just to add the `z-index: 1000;` property directly to the element as inline style, not a general css change that would apply to all `bracket-part`s (see my code snippet)