# Overlapping divs with opaque background

Tags: html, css

I have two `div`s with a background color, one overlapping the other. The problem is that I can see the content of the underlying `div` through the top `div`.

https://jsfiddle.net/jost_s/0dxwtbvn/23/

```css
div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.overlapping {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div>AB</div>
<div class="overlapping">CD</div>
```

Comment: use position:relative so it is paint at front. use z-index also if other content is also positioned https://jsfiddle.net/c57z6n84/

Comment: Please post your code in your question, not on a third party site.

Comment: @j08691 okay, done

Comment: @j08691 agreed, this is a duplicate and can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `transform: translate();` to position the elements instead of margin.
Since its triggering the stacking context and assure that the elements are "stacket" in the right way.

I cannot really explain why margin behaves in this way but maybe someone     wants to educate me.

```css
div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.overlapping {
  border: 1px solid white;
  transform: translate(50px, -50px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    AB
  </p>

</div>
<div class="overlapping">
  <p>
    CD
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Both solutions work, `position: relative` and `transform`. I accepted this answer because it involves less changes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: relative`

```css
div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.overlapping {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
AB
</div>
<div class="overlapping">
CD
</div>
```

Comment: Why? While that appears to resolve the issue, why does that work?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know that too.

Answer (score 1):

Without a `position` property, they're not really overlapping in the context of the way the browser renders them.

There's probably a better explanation of why the second block overlaps the first block, but not it's content, but I'm sure it involves a deep understanding of how the rendering engine works. You might even get a different result in different browsers.

To get the desired effect, position the overlapping block instead of using the margin...

```css
div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.overlapping {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  left: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  AB
</div>
<div class="overlapping">
  CD
</div>
```

Comment: not really deep understanding but need to find where it's defined in the Specification which is tricky. Full detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48731110/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif Our definitions of what is considered a deep understanding differ significantly   

Your linked question was clearly well-researched, but you still had to speculate as to why, exactly, it was happening. The top answer (6 full page lengths to read on my screen) starts with a warning: "Reading the following information can affect your mental health." (bounty awarded, but answer not accepted??).

Comment: I didn't accept any answer because I didn't get the answer I was waiting .. the top answer gave me where this was defined but I am still looking for *why* it was defined like that. What is the reason of such non intuitve choice. I my self gave an answer but based on my own thinking like the other answers too.