# What is the correct painting or rendering order of my given HTML elements having CSS styles?

Tags: html, css

Here is the [painting order algorithm description](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html). I have tried to understand this algorithm for the following output:

```css
span {
  border: 20px solid fuchsia;
}

div.inside {
  border: 10px solid black;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inside">First Block Div</div>
  <span>Inline Span</span>
  <div class="inside">Second Block Div</div>
</div>
```

[image: The result of the snippet as an image]

According to the algorithm, the painting order should be:

1. Container div Border
2. First Div Background and Border
3. Second Div Background and Border
4. Span Background and Border
5. First Div Text
6. Span Text
7. Second Div Text

but here is the problem, if the first div text is painted after span's border then we should be clearly able to see first div's content which is "First Block Div" but in output image the first div's content is overlapped by span's border... how is this happening? That's what I want to understand... If I have made any mistake in understanding the algorithm then please correct me.

Comment: Why not edit your previous question instead of posting a new one with basically the same question? I guess you wanted to remove the IE thing?

Comment: my previous question was closed. and this is another question from the suggested answer from stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't pretend to have a complete understanding of the stacking order spec, but the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731110/why-the-content-is-not-covered-by-the-background-of-an-overlapping-element) of your previous question seems to cover it in quite a lot of detail, have you checked whether it explains this result?

Comment: @DBS yes i have read those details and still I had some confusion regarding the output which I posted above. So, I posted a question. may be someone can correct my understanding of the algorithm.

Comment: @somethinghere the previous question was closed because it was duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified painting order algorithm (which runs on preorder depth-first search tree traversal mechanism) for non-positioned in-flow descendant elements, considering none of the elements are creating a stacking context:

```
    ----------------- First Iteration of Tree Traversal ------------------
    
    1. If the element is a non-positioned block-level descendant:
      1. background color of element
      2. border of element
    2. If the element is a non-positioned inline descendant:
      1. do nothing and skip the element
    
    ----------------- Second Iteration of Tree Traversal -----------------
    
    1. If the element is a non-positioned block-level descendant:
      1. print its text content 
    2. If the element is a non-positioned inline descendant:
      1. background color of element
      2. border of element
      3. text content of element
```

Note 1: This above algorithm follows the step 4 and step 7 of the painting order algorithm defined in CSS 2.1 [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html).

For following code,

```css
span {
  border: 20px solid fuchsia;
  background-color: green;
}

div.first-div, div.second-div {
  border: 10px solid black;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-div">First Block Div</div>
  <span>Inline Span</span>
  <div class="second-div">Second Block Div</div>
</div>
```

Note 2: Here, all the elements in our example, like parent div, child divs, and span, do not create any stacking context. But, they reside inside the default stacking context formed by an html element.

Note 3: Here, consider the parent (root) block-level div element as a descendant (child) element of an html element.

[Tree Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEXXr.png)

Now according to preorder depth-first search algo., root element is visited first in first iteration, so background color of the root element (in our case, container div is the root element) is painted first.

Now continuing the traversal from left to right OR top to bottom in our HTML document, on left side or top side, first div is visited first and background color of the the first div is painted first and then border of the first div is painted. now the traversal finds second div after visiting span, now here in this first iteration, text content of root element + text content of both divs + span element are skipped because this first iteration of preorder depth first traversal is only for painting root element's background color and background color + border of the block level descendant elements in tree order. so second div is visited and background color of the the second div is painted and then border of the second div is painted.

Now the first iteration ends and second iteration starts. now root element's css style is already painted and it has no text content, so skip root element and now again first div is visited after root element and the first div's text content is the only remaining part so the text content of first div is printed.

Now the traversal in second iteration continues and visits the span element (going from left to right OR top to bottom in our HTML document) and thus background color of span element is painted first and then border of the span element is painted and at last the text content of the span element is printed.

Now finally, the traversal in second iteration visits the last div (second div) element (going from left to right) and as we know the background color and border of second div are already painted, so this time text content of the second div is printed.

Now second iteration ends and no more iterations because our elements are fully painted...

So, final painting order in brief:

1. background color of container div
2. first div background color + border
3. second div background color + border
4. first div's text content
5. span background color + border
6. span's text content
7. second div's text content

Note 4: Having an inline-level parent element and block-level descendent (child) elements is not a recommended practice according to the HTML specs. but if you are curious to know the painting order for inline-level root (parent) element having block and inline-level descendant (child) elements then have a look at the following tree diagram which has a painting order mentioned via numbers:

[Tree Diagram for inline root (parent) element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zehpe.png)

for code,

```
<div class="first-div">First Block Div</div>
<div class="second-div">Second Block Div</div>
<span>Inline Span</span>
```

The painting order will be:

1. first div background color + border
2. second div background color + border
3. first div text content
4. second div text content
5. span background color + border
6. span text content

for code,

```
<span>Inline Span</span>
<div class="first-div">First Block Div</div>
<div class="second-div">Second Block Div</div>
```

The painting order will be:

1. first div background color + border
2. second div background color + border
3. span background color + border
4. span text content
5. first div text content
6. second div text content