# Stacking order of <img> and elements with negative margin

Tags: html, css

I tried putting a `<div>` below an `<img>` with a negative margin, but the `<img>` ended up covering the `<div>`. I am confused because the `<img>` is not positioned, and is not creating a stacking context, so there seems to have no reason for the `<img>` to go against the natural rendering order of HTML.

When I used `display: flex`, everything worked as expected, which makes me even more confused. Can someone explain this to me? Are there any specs that outline this behavior?

```css
.img {
  display: block;
}

.square {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  background-color: green;
}

#flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

#container > * {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <img class="img" src="https://placehold.co/100">
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="flex">
    <img class="img" src="https://placehold.co/100">
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both behaviors are correct. In a normal flow (your first example), the content always have the priority over the background of adjacent elements so the image will get painted above the background.

Here is a relevant question with full detail: [Why the content is not covered by the background of an overlapping element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48731110/8620333)

When you make the container a flexbox one, the painting algorithm is modified because flex items behave differently

> Flex items paint exactly the same as **inline blocks** <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting)</sup>

inline block elements are painted as a whole element like the ones that create stacking context so no more interaction with the content of sibling elements

> For inline-block and inline-table elements:
>
> 1 For each one of these, treat the element as if it created a new stacking context, <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/zindex.html)</sup>

---

Here is another example with text content on the second div to better understand the first case:

```css
.img {
  display: block;
}

.square {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  background-color: green;
}

#flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

#container > * {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <img class="img" src="https://placehold.co/100">
    <div class="square"> text content</div>
  </div>

  <div id="flex">
    <img class="img" src="https://placehold.co/100">
    <div class="square"> text content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The text is always painted above the image and only the background is behind. By making the container a flexbox one, you change this behavior.